# How to change any environment property value using Spring

Tags: java, spring

Just as we can read the property using @Value annotation, is there any way to change the value of the property through the code?

```
@Value("#{envProps['" + Keys.Env.updatedDate + "']}")
  private String date;
```

value in environment.properties

```
     updatedDate =2013-10-01
```

I want to change the value to 2013-10-16. How to do it?

Thanks

Comment: sorry not clear when yiu say how to change value throug code, you can simply call the property setter method ?

Answer (score 0):

## Sorry you cant do that

`@Annotations` and its values in java are `constants`.

the `@Annotations` are stored in class file (at `RuntimeVisibleAnnotations`) while compiling.
the values of them can be String, Class, or other value and can't be change at Runtime.

see [jvm class file spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.16)

## Alternative solution

use a place holder like

```
   @Value("${updatedDate.envProps}")
   private String date;
```

and write your custom [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) to parse `updatedDate.envProps` to the value you want